# Node.js: Syntax Error on exporting

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is really fundamental... I am just getting started with Node.js.

I have a simple module

server.js

```
var http = require("http");

function start() {
    function onRequest() {
        console.log("Request received");
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("Hello World");
        response.end();
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server has started...");
}

export.start = start;
```

and it's being called from index.js as follows

```
var server = require("./server");
server.start();
```

but running `node index.js` gives me this!

```
$ node index.js

d:\SourceRepo\node-sample\server.js:15
export.start = start;
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Module._compile (module.js:437:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\SourceRepo\node-sample\index.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

How to sort this out? I am a newbie to JavaScript!

Comment: export is in fact a reserved word in javascript

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `exports`, with an "s".

Comment: oops a typo! vi highlighted it's kind of keyword... so I did not notice.. thanks.

Comment: It's right, it is! Just not the word you were looking for. :)